# PHP Curl: Set -J and -O options to download file by remote file name

Tags: php, curl, download

I'd like to download a file from a php script using curl.
I want to write the file with the same name as the remote file (which is not included in the url).
I can achieve this in the bash by using the options -O and -J. 
Example:

```
curl -XGET -O -J http://AAA.com/asdasd/Default.aspx?pid=somethingsomethignsomething
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2388k  100 2388k    0     0   304k      0  0:00:07  0:00:07 --:--:--  248k

curl: Saved to filename 'file_20151206.txt'
```

As you can see, the name of the file is file_20151206.txt, and it's the remote name of the file, which is NOT contained in the url.

How can I do this in php?, I couldn't find any help in the documentation.

Comment: This is really bad. If the Response Header Content-Disposition is present, then the filename is in the value of the header. If it's not, then the filename may or may not be in the url :(. Any other way to solve this???